# Yammer embed shows bad open graph data

Tags: yammer

We have a intranet portal with a blog section. We would like to have Yammer comments for the blog posts. We are using the [Yammer Embed Commenting](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/commenting) feature. The feature works correctly except it doesn't pull the open graph data from the page, instead it defaults to Yammer's info (see image).

There is also an error on the page GET https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/likes/open_graph_object/351561199203555?_=1422308845424 404 (Not Found)

About the site

- Uses SSL
- Requires Yammer Authentication to access using OAuth
- Accessible from outside our intranet

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the because of the sites authentication.

We needed to specify the OG data in the javascript that initializes the embed. Code follows:

```
yam.connect.embedFeed({
 container: "#embedded-feed",
 network: "fourleaf.com",
 feedType: "open-graph",
 objectProperties: {
   url: "https://box.com/file/abc123",
   type:  "file",
   title: "Yammer ROI.pdf",
   image: "https://dox.com/file/abc123.png"
 }
});
```

Comment: I know this post is old, but it's 2017 and I'm getting exactly the same issue. could you be more specific on what "specify the OG data" means?

Comment: As you said it's been a long time. I can't remember much but I believe the OG or Open Graph data I was referring to is all of the data the object passed to embedFeed. Try this and see if it helps https://www.yammer.com/widget/configure

Comment: Yammer weirdism .. if the page has "a comment" (i.e. from anyone) then there are no errors .. otherwise Chrome reports a 404. Same applies for actionButtons (as soon as someone "likes" the page, the 404 errors disappear).

Comment: Yes. Yammer is strange. Unfortunately I don't work with it anymore so I won't be much help. My best guess would be to download Fiddler and see if the network traffic shows anything that makes sense.